# Retrofit onResponse not working but onFailure can be execute

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, pojo

Can anyone help me? I use `Log.e("CHART_RESPONSE", "sus" );` to see where it executes, and it shows in `OnFailure`. I've been trying to solve it for the past three days but it still couldn't get it to work. Please help me.

[image]

This is API code:

```
public interface Api {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("register.php")
    Call<RegisterResponse> register(
            @Field("voltage") String voltage,
            @Field("current") String current,
            @Field("temp") String temp
    );
  @GET("fetch.php")
  Call<ChartResponse> init();

}
```

RetrofitClient code:

```
package com.example.apiapp;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    private static OkHttpClient buildClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient
                .Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
                .build();
    }

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            Gson gson=new Gson();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(buildClient())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))

                    /**
                     *
                     *  base url here for api
                     */

                    .baseUrl("http://192.8.1.103/PHP-API/")
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

JSON code:

```json
[
    {
        "voltage": [
            "110.53",
            "110.28",
            "0.00",
            "0.00",
            "0.00"
        ]
    },
    {
        "current": [
            "10.79",
            "4.93",
            "100.80",
            "0.00",
            "0.00"
        ]
    },
    {
        "temp": [
            "28.54",
            "34.00",
            "35.77",
            "0.00",
            "0.00"
        ]
    },
    {
        "hum": [
            "31.00",
            "90.13",
            "3.80",
            "0.00",
            "0.00"
        ]
    }
]
```

json pojo(I convert it from jsonschema2pojo):

```
public class ChartResponse{
    @SerializedName("voltage")
    @Expose
    private static List<String> voltage;
    @SerializedName("current")
    @Expose
    private  static List<Float> current;
    @SerializedName("temp")
    @Expose
    private  static List<Float> temp;
    @SerializedName("hum")
    @Expose
    private  static List<Float> hum;

    public static List<String> getVoltage() {
        return voltage;
    }

    public void setVoltage(List<String> voltage) {
        this.voltage = voltage;
    }

    public static List<Float> getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    public void setCurrent(List<Float> current) {
        this.current = current;
    }

    public static List<Float> getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(List<Float> temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public static List<Float> getHum() {
        return hum;
    }

    public void setHum(List<Float> hum) {
        this.hum = hum;
    }
    }
```

barchart code:

```
public class barchart extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static Object data;
    public Api api;
    private Object chartResponse;
    ArrayList<ChartResponse> chartList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.barchart_main);
   
        api = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(Api.class);
        getData();
        Button Hi =findViewById(R.id.button);
        Hi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(barchart.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    /**
     * api call to get some data from server
     */


    private void getData() {

        Call<ChartResponse> call = api.init();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ChartResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ChartResponse> call, Response<ChartResponse> response) {
                Log.e("CHART_RESPONSE", "sus" );
                BarChart barchart = findViewById(R.id.fragment_verticalbarchart_chart);
                Log.d("CHART_RESPONSE", "success" + response.body().getVoltage());
               // ChartResponse chartresponse=response.body();
                ArrayList<Float> dataSets = new ArrayList<Float>();
                ArrayList<BarEntry> completed = new ArrayList<>();
                /**
                 *  Getting the value for Complete list
                 */
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    
                   BarEntry value = new BarEntry(ChartResponse.getHum().get(i), i); 
                   completed.add(value);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < dataSets.size(); i++) {
                    BarEntry barEntry = new BarEntry(i, dataSets.get(i));
                    completed.add(barEntry);
                }
                BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(completed, "Completed Issue");
                /**
                 *  Add complete data into the bar chart
                 */
                barDataSet.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));
                BarData data = new BarData(barDataSet);
                barchart.setData(data);
                barchart.invalidate();
                barchart.setData(data);
                barchart.invalidate();



            }

           @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ChartResponse>call, Throwable t) {
               Log.e("CHART_RESPONSE", "sfs" );
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I've added:

```
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
```

and in manifest:
`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Rename Api interface to other name.

You may have imported another interface in your barchart Activity like (import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api;
)

Comment: Thank you! I change the name but still cannot work

Answer (score 0):

In `onFailure`, the second parameter is a `Throwable`, which is the error that is thrown.
Log that value, or set a debug breakpoint and check it out. It will tell you why it's failing.
Always check any kind of Throwable/Exception.

Though i do see an error in your code.
All 4 arrays that are returned in your JSON response are List values, but you've set 3 of them as List values, that won't work.

There still might be other errors though.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found my problem which is IOException and I'm now trying to fix it!